# Galera SST fails

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I am using MariaDB 10.2

I have node2 (2.2.2.2) running as a slave to some external database.
I bootstrapped node2 as the first member of a Galera cluster "my_cluster"

When I try to join node1 (1.1.1.1) to the cluster I get failures.

I see 4 rsync processes running on node1:

```
mysql    20458  0.0  0.0   4504   788 ?        S    10:49   0:00 sh -c wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'joiner' --address '1.1.1.1:4444' --datadir '/var/mysql/datadir/'   --parent '20440' --binlog '/var/mysql/log/mysql-bin' 
mysql    20459  0.0  0.0   4504  1712 ?        S    10:49   0:00 /bin/sh -ue /usr//bin/wsrep_sst_rsync --role joiner --address 1.1.1.1:4444 --datadir /var/mysql/datadir/ --parent 20440 --binlog /var/mysql/log/mysql-bin
mysql    20500  0.0  0.0  12784  2636 ?        S    10:49   0:00 rsync --daemon --no-detach --port 4444 --config /var/mysql/datadir//rsync_sst.conf
mysql    20755  0.0  0.0  26528  2844 ?        S    10:49   0:00 rsync --daemon --no-detach --port 4444 --config /var/mysql/datadir//rsync_sst.conf
mysql    20779  9.8  0.0  26788  1460 ?        R    10:49   1:00 rsync --daemon --no-detach --port 4444 --config /var/mysql/datadir//rsync_sst.conf
```

and on node2:

```
mysql    25860  0.0  0.0   4504   748 ?        S    10:49   0:00 sh -c wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'donor' --address '1.1.1.1:4444/rsync_sst' --socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' --datadir '/var/mysql/datadir/'    --binlog '/var/mysql/log/mysql-bin' --gtid '09e3b6c8-343c-11e8-87cf-07a9813fdf95:0' --gtid-domain-id '0'
mysql    25861  0.0  0.0   4504  1704 ?        S    10:49   0:00 /bin/sh -ue /usr//bin/wsrep_sst_rsync --role donor --address 1.1.1.1:4444/rsync_sst --socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --datadir /var/mysql/datadir/ --binlog /var/mysql/log/mysql-bin --gtid 09e3b6c8-343c-11e8-87cf-07a9813fdf95:0 --gtid-domain-id 0
mysql    25909  0.0  0.0   6468  1960 ?        S    10:49   0:00 xargs -I{} -0 -P 8 rsync --owner --group --perms --links --specials --ignore-times --inplace --recursive --delete --quiet --whole-file --exclude */ib_logfile* /var/mysql/datadir//{}/ rsync://1.1.1.1:4444/rsync_sst/{}
mysql    25910 11.8  0.0  22604  3244 ?        S    10:49   1:39 rsync --owner --group --perms --links --specials --ignore-times --inplace --recursive --delete --quiet --whole-file --exclude */ib_logfile* /var/mysql/datadir//./db1/ rsync://1.1.1.1:4444/rsync_sst/./db1
```

However port 444 is only open on node1 and the file rsync_sst.conf in datadir is not increasing.

I have apparmor an ufw completely disabled.
Firewall allows:

- TCP from all nodes on 4444
- TCP and UDP from all nodes on 4567
- TCP from all nodes on 4568
- TCP from all nodes on 3306

node2 my.cnf

```
binlog_format=row
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_slave_threads=1
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name="my_cluster"
# for bootstrapping
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://"
#wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://2.2.2.2,1.1.1.1"
wsrep_sst_receive_address=2.2.2.2:4444
wsrep_provider_options='ist.recv_addr=2.2.2.2:4568;'
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_node_address="2.2.2.2"
wsrep_node_name="node2"
```

node1 my.cnf

```
binlog_format=row
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_slave_threads=1
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name="my_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://2.2.2.2"
# also tried below
#wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://2.2.2.2,1.1.1.1"
wsrep_sst_receive_address=1.1.1.1:4444
wsrep_provider_options='ist.recv_addr=1.1.1.1:4568;'
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_donor="node2,"
wsrep_node_address="1.1.1.1"
wsrep_node_name="node1"
```

node1 error.log

```
Apr  3 10:49:23 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon...
Apr  3 10:49:23 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysql[19997]:  * Starting MariaDB database server mysqld
Apr  3 10:49:23 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld_safe: Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/mysql/datadir
Apr  3 10:49:23 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld_safe: WSREP: Running position recovery with --disable-log-error  --pid-file='/var/mysql/datadir/MY_CLUSTER_NODE1-recover.pid'
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld_safe: WSREP: Recovered position 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.2.14-MariaDB-10.2.14+maria~xenial-log) starting as process 20440 ...
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library '/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so'
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): Galera 25.3.23(r3789) by Codership Oy <info@codership.com> loaded successfully.
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: CRC-32C: using hardware acceleration.
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: Found saved state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1, safe_to_bootstrap: 1
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: Passing config to GCS: base_dir = /var/mysql/datadir/; base_host = 1.1.1.1; base_port = 4567; cert.log_conflicts = no; debug = no; evs.auto_evict = 0; evs.delay_margin = PT1S; evs.delayed_keep_period = PT30S; evs.inactive_check_period = PT0.5S; evs.inactive_timeout = PT15S; evs.join_retrans_period = PT1S; evs.max_install_timeouts = 3; evs.send_window = 4; evs.stats_report_period = PT1M; evs.suspect_timeout = PT5S; evs.user_send_window = 2; evs.view_forget_timeout = PT24H; gcache.dir = /var/mysql/datadir/; gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; gcache.mem_size = 0; gcache.name = /var/mysql/datadir//galera.cache; gcache.page_size = 128M; gcache.recover = no; gcache.size = 128M; gcomm.thread_prio = ; gcs.fc_debug = 0; gcs.fc_factor = 1.0; gcs.fc_limit = 16; gcs.fc_master_slave = no; gcs.max_packet_size = 64500; gcs.max_throttle = 0.25; gcs.recv_q_hard_limit = 9223372036854775807; gcs.recv_q_soft_limit = 0.25; gcs.sync_donor = no; gmcast.seg
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: ment = 0; gmcast.version = 0; ist.recv_addr = 1.1.1.1:4568; pc.a
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: GCache history reset: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:0 -> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: -1, protocol version: -1
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_sst_grab()
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: Start replication
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: Setting initial position to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: protonet asio version 0
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: Using CRC-32C for message checksums.
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: backend: asio
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: gcomm thread scheduling priority set to other:0
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Warning] WSREP: access file(/var/mysql/datadir//gvwstate.dat) failed(No such file or directory)
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: restore pc from disk failed
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: GMCast version 0
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: (8854b393, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') listening at tcp://0.0.0.0:4567
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: (8854b393, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') multicast: , ttl: 1
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: EVS version 0
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connecting to group 'my_cluster', peer '2.2.2.2:'
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: (8854b393, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection established to d1198d28 tcp://2.2.2.2:4567
Apr  3 10:49:26 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:26 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: (8854b393, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting on, nonlive peers:
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: declaring d1198d28 at tcp://2.2.2.2:4567 stable
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: Node d1198d28 state prim
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,8854b393,6) memb {
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: #0118854b393,0
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: #011d1198d28,0
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: } joined {
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: } left {
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: } partitioned {
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: })
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: save pc into disk
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connected
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: Changing maximum packet size to 64500, resulting msg size: 32636
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: Shifting CLOSED -> OPEN (TO: 0)
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: Opened channel 'my_cluster'
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084015769344 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 0, memb_num = 2
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084453714112 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete.
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084015769344 [Note] WSREP: STATE_EXCHANGE: sent state UUID: 88ed85fa-3713-11e8-b4e1-cf323f71d772
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084015769344 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: 88ed85fa-3713-11e8-b4e1-cf323f71d772
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084015769344 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 88ed85fa-3713-11e8-b4e1-cf323f71d772 from 0 (node1)
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084015769344 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 88ed85fa-3713-11e8-b4e1-cf323f71d772 from 1 (node2)
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084015769344 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: #011version    = 4,
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: #011component  = PRIMARY,
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: #011conf_id    = 5,
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: #011members    = 1/2 (joined/total),
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: #011act_id     = 0,
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: #011last_appl. = -1,
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: #011protocols  = 0/8/3 (gcs/repl/appl),
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: #011group UUID = 09e3b6c8-343c-11e8-87cf-07a9813fdf95
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084015769344 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [23, 23]
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084015769344 [Note] WSREP: Trying to continue unpaused monitor
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084015769344 [Note] WSREP: Shifting OPEN -> PRIMARY (TO: 0)
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084256552704 [Note] WSREP: State transfer required:
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: #011Group state: 09e3b6c8-343c-11e8-87cf-07a9813fdf95:0
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: #011Local state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084256552704 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: 09e3b6c8-343c-11e8-87cf-07a9813fdf95:0, view# 6: Primary, number of nodes: 2, my index: 0, protocol version 3
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084256552704 [Warning] WSREP: Gap in state sequence. Need state transfer.
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:27 140084007376640 [Note] WSREP: Running: 'wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'joiner' --address '1.1.1.1:4444' --datadir '/var/mysql/datadir/'   --parent '20440' --binlog '/var/mysql/log/mysql-bin' '
Apr  3 10:49:27 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20500]: rsyncd version 3.1.1 starting, listening on port 4444
Apr  3 10:49:28 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:28 140084256552704 [Note] WSREP: Prepared SST request: rsync|1.1.1.1:4444/rsync_sst
Apr  3 10:49:28 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:28 140084256552704 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
Apr  3 10:49:28 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:28 140084256552704 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 8 (3, 2)
Apr  3 10:49:28 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:28 140084256552704 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 0, protocol version: 3
Apr  3 10:49:28 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:28 140084265998080 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
Apr  3 10:49:28 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:28 140084256552704 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to prepare for incremental state transfer: Local state UUID (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) does not match group state UUID (09e3b6c8-343c-11e8-87cf-07a9813fdf95): 1 (Operation not permitted)
Apr  3 10:49:28 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: #011 at galera/src/replicator_str.cpp:prepare_for_IST():482. IST will be unavailable.
Apr  3 10:49:28 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:28 140084015769344 [Note] WSREP: Member 0.0 (node1) requested state transfer from 'node2,'. Selected 1.0 (node2)(SYNCED) as donor.
Apr  3 10:49:28 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:28 140084015769344 [Note] WSREP: Shifting PRIMARY -> JOINER (TO: 0)
Apr  3 10:49:28 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:28 140084256552704 [Note] WSREP: Requesting state transfer: success, donor: 1
Apr  3 10:49:28 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:28 140084256552704 [Note] WSREP: GCache history reset: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:0 -> 09e3b6c8-343c-11e8-87cf-07a9813fdf95:0
Apr  3 10:49:28 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20530]: connect from ec2-node2.amazonaws.com (2.2.2.2)
Apr  3 10:49:28 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20530]: rsync to rsync_sst/ from ec2-node2.amazonaws.com (2.2.2.2)
Apr  3 10:49:29 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20530]: receiving file list
Apr  3 10:49:30 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysqld: 2018-04-03 10:49:30 140084024162048 [Note] WSREP: (8854b393, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off
Apr  3 10:49:33 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20530]: sent 75 bytes  received 79721974 bytes  total size 79702016
Apr  3 10:49:33 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20597]: connect from ec2-node2.amazonaws.com (2.2.2.2)
Apr  3 10:49:33 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20597]: rsync to rsync_sst-log_dir/ from ec2-node2.amazonaws.com (2.2.2.2)
Apr  3 10:49:33 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20597]: receiving file list
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20597]: sent 63 bytes  received 268501210 bytes  total size 268435456
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 kernel: [85332.768269] TCP: request_sock_TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 4444. Sending cookies.  Check SNMP counters.
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20755]: connect from ec2-node2.amazonaws.com (2.2.2.2)
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20756]: connect from ec2-node2.amazonaws.com (2.2.2.2)
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20757]: connect from ec2-node2.amazonaws.com (2.2.2.2)
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20758]: connect from ec2-node2.amazonaws.com (2.2.2.2)
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20759]: connect from ec2-node2.amazonaws.com (2.2.2.2)
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20760]: connect from ec2-node2.amazonaws.com (2.2.2.2)
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20757]: rsync to rsync_sst/./db2 from ec2-node2.amazonaws.com (2.2.2.2)
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20756]: rsync to rsync_sst/./db3 from ec2-node2.amazonaws.com (2.2.2.2)
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20755]: rsync to rsync_sst/./db1 from ec2-node2.amazonaws.com (2.2.2.2)
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20758]: rsync to rsync_sst/./mysql from ec2-node2.amazonaws.com (2.2.2.2)
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20760]: rsync to rsync_sst/./db4 from ec2-node2.amazonaws.com (2.2.2.2)
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20759]: rsync to rsync_sst/./performance_schema from ec2-node2.amazonaws.com (2.2.2.2)
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20757]: receiving file list
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20756]: receiving file list
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20755]: receiving file list
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20759]: receiving file list
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20760]: receiving file list
Apr  3 10:49:46 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20758]: receiving file list
Apr  3 10:49:47 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20759]: sent 48 bytes  received 214 bytes  total size 61
Apr  3 10:49:47 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20760]: sent 314 bytes  received 805861 bytes  total size 804574
Apr  3 10:49:47 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20758]: sent 1682 bytes  received 6771484 bytes  total size 6763799
Apr  3 10:49:48 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 rsyncd[20757]: sent 1074 bytes  received 20618935 bytes  total size 20610082
Apr  3 10:49:55 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 /etc/init.d/mysql[20905]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Apr  3 10:49:55 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 /etc/init.d/mysql[20905]: #007/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
Apr  3 10:49:55 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 /etc/init.d/mysql[20905]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)'
Apr  3 10:49:55 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 mysql[19997]:    ...fail!
Apr  3 10:49:55 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 /etc/init.d/mysql[20905]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
Apr  3 10:49:55 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr  3 10:49:55 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 /etc/init.d/mysql[20905]: 
Apr  3 10:49:55 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Apr  3 10:49:55 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr  3 10:49:55 MY_CLUSTER_NODE1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Have you verified that the nodes can reach eachother? The "no route to host" message seems to indicate rsync on node1 can't reach node2. Can you ssh from node1 to node2, using IP address 2.2.2.2?

Comment: I cannot ssh because port 22 is not open.

Comment: Ah yes, rsync is using port 4444 I think, which you've already said is open. Have a look at my answer below instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wsrep_sst_donor=2.2.2.2
```

[wsrep_sst_donor](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/galera-cluster-system-variables/#wsrep_sst_donor) should have the node name, not the IP address.

A similar case was reported in the MariaDB Jira as [MDEV-13687](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13687).

Comment: I let the processes finish on their own. When they completed I started the mysql service on node1 and everything worked.